# How to add customer group attribute?

Tags: product, product-attribute

Can we add group of customer attribute for max quantity at time of product insertion.

i have explain in image please follow the image.[image]

Comment: Personally I love this question. But it is too broad to answer. Short answer is, you need to create a custom extension to implement this.